# Why don't equivalence transformations preserve derivatives?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have a very simple question I'm unable to answer.

I have calculated the following derivative

$$ \frac{0.56}{x^2} = 0.42$$

The next derivative is

$$ 0 - \frac{1.12}{x^3} = 0$$

However If I take the first derivative and transform it to

$$ 0.56 = 0.42 * x^2$$

The next derivative is:

$$2*0.42*x => 0.84x$$

So equivalence transformations are not allowed when handling derivatives? I'm sorry If this question is at a very low level.

Comment: I am completely lost here. what do you mean exactly by "I have calculated the following derivative" and then writing down an equation?

Comment: You're far from the first person to have noticed this. See [taking the derivative of both sides of an equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3240322/taking-the-derivative-of-both-sides-of-an-equation).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is differentiating on both sides of an equation allowed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1475013/is-differentiating-on-both-sides-of-an-equation-allowed). In short, you need both functions to be equal to each other for all values of $x$, rather than only for certain values of $x$.

Comment: So basically when handling derivatives the safe way is to bring all the terms on one side and then take the derivative?