# If two functions are mirror images of each other about the line $y=x$, are they inverses of each other?

Tags: functions, inverse, inverse-function

I know that for a function $f$ there exists an inverse $f^{-1}$ when $f$ is one-one and onto in its domain. I also know that a function $f$ and its inverse $f^{-1}$ are mirror images about the line $y=x$.

Now, can we say that when two functions which are exactly mirror images about the line $y=x$, are inverses of each other? Or in other words is the converse of the statement "*Function and its inverse are mirror images of each other about the line $y=x$*" is always true? If it is not always true, kindly give me circumstances when the converse fails.

---

Edit:

From [this](https://qr.ae/TW2ZG5) Quora answer, it is said that two functions having the same graph need not necessarily be equal. Then how can we conclude that the graph mirror imaged about the line $y=x$ is definitely its inverse?

Comment: Ignoring possible issues with domains and ranges, your converse statement is true.

Comment: +1 Good question because the converse is frequently assumed to be true. I myself use the converse quite often without ever considering if it is actually true.

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3394288/can-two-different-functions-have-the-same-graph

Comment: Related : [Difference between function and equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1603753/693070)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the two functions whose graphs are reflections over the line $y=x$ are named $f$ and $g$. What does it even mean to say the graphs are reflections over the line $y=x$? It means that if $(a,b)$ is some point on $f$'s graph, then $(b,a)$ is a point on $g$'s graph.

So take any $a$ in $f$'s domain, and let $b=f(a)$. Then the point $(a,b)$ is on $f$'s graph. So $(b,a)$ is on $g$'s graph. So $g(b)=a$. So $g(f(a))=a$. And this was for an arbitrary $a$ is $f$'s domain. The argument is symmetric for showing that for any $b$ in $g$'s domain, that $f(g(b))=b$. So the conclusion is yes, $f$ and $g$ are inverses.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In this [Quora answer](https://qr.ae/TW2ZG5), it is given that two functions having same graph need not be equivalent and [here at math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3394288/693070) it totally confuses me. I completely understood your answer. But based on that Quora answer, it is also equally correct to claim the graph mirrored about $y=x$ may not be the inverse of the original graph. It would be great if you could explain this.

Comment: @Intellex Do you understand the difference between a "function" and an "equation"? That Quora answer is about two _equations_ in $x$ and $y$, and the solutions to the two equations make the same graph. But two _functions_ with the same graph are indeed the same _function_.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, because if one function is $y = f(x)$, the other is $x = g(y)$, since swapping $x$ and $y$ has the same effect as reflecting across the line $y=x$.

Substituting the first into the second, $x = g(y) = g(f(x))$, or in other words, $g^{-1} (x) = f(x)$ if $g^{-1} (x)$ exists. Similarly, substituting the other way around, $y = f(x) = f(g(y)$, so $f^{-1} (y) = g(y)$ if $f^{-1} (y)$ exists.

Comment: I might make them different functions.. This is making it seem like $f$ is an involution which it need not be.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have now edited.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I could not think of any situation when the converse doesn't hold good. So, are there any circumstances when two functions are mirror images about $y=x$ but **not inverses** of each other?

Comment: No, because if two functions are inverses of each other, then there is a bijection between the two functions. For example, if $f(x) = x+2$, $f^{-1} (x) = x-2$, and the point $(7,9)$ of $f(x)$ corresponds to $(9,7)$ on $f^{-1} (x)$. Since the mirror image exists, then there has to be a bijection where you can construct an inverse.

Comment: @TobyMak, Could you please read the question again, I have added some details.

Comment: You are scaring yourself here. Rewriting $(y-x)(x^2+y^2)$ to isolate $y$, you get $y=x$, and rewriting $y-x=0$ you also get $y=x$. This shows that for both functions, each value of $x$ still corresponds to the same value of $y$.

Comment: I suppose we should add in that both functions can be continuous, since you cannot really talk about bijections unless there is a value of $x$ for each value of $y$. Also, both functions should be one-to-one, unless you restrict them to a particular range which makes them one-to-one (such as $y=x^2$ in the range $x ≥ 0$).

Comment: @TobyMak, WRT your first comment today, I understand that. But still the formulae for the two cases look different - for one is of order 3 and the other of order 1.

Comment: So two functions with same graphs are necessarily equal, and not unequal as said in the Quora answer.

Comment: As far as I know, two functions are equal if and only if they have the same formula and same domain. Are there any exceptions to this rule?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99679/discussion-between-intellex-and-toby-mak).